# MySQL: How can I use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with LIMIT and at the same get the SUM of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` can be used together with `LIMIT` to get all items needed. But my problem is that I also want to get the SUM of a column of all those items. I tried the following:

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, SUM('score') FROM `tab` WHERE 1
LIMIT 1, 10"
```

Interestingly, it returns only one item instead of 10 as it is supposed to. I am pretty sure it is caused by the `SUM` function as when I remove the `SUM` function, it returns 10 items correctly. So how do I achieve what I want **and why the above one is not working**?

To be concise, take the following table as an example:

```
id name score
1  abc  10
2  def  20
3  abc  30
```

I would like to return the following results:

```
id name score total_score
1  abc  10    40
2  def  20    20
3  abc  10    40
```

Another related question is: I know that total_score is repeating itself for the same user. So the related question is: **Is using one query (if it is possible) better than two queries in this case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `GROUP BY` clause along with using an aggregation function like `SUM`.

For example, if your structure was something like this:

```
create table tab (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  gamename varchar(20),
  score int
);

insert into tab (gamename, score) values 
('game1', 20),
('game2', 30),
('game3', 40),
('game2', 60);
```

Your query to extract the sum would look like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS gamename, SUM(score) 
FROM `tab` 
group by gamename
LIMIT 1, 10;

-- Results
gamename  sum(score)
--------  ----------
game2     90
game3     40

select found_rows();
found_rows()
------------
3
```

Hope this helps out.

**Corresponding edit to the question**

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, b.totals
from tab a 
inner join (
    select gamename, sum(score) as totals
    from tab 
    group by gamename
) b on a.gamename = b.gamename
limit 0, 2;

-- Result
id  gamename  score  totals
--  --------  -----  ------
1   game1     20     20
2   game2     30     90

select found_rows();
found_rows()
------------
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is actually NOT what I want. I would like to return all items, not grouped items. As in your example, I would like to have two items of user game2, rather than 1. I understand that total score for game2 should have only one result, but I don't mind having it repeating in all items of game2. As I can use something like $data[0][sum_score] to get that total score.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks. BTW, do you have any idea on the subquestion of "Is using one query better than two queries in this case?"

Comment: Percona has a great article about that. Two queries will be faster in many cases. https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/